# How to replace space with another value?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I am having file with `|` as delimiter, approximately 8k records.

If column#3 is empty I want to replace it with the value from column#2. How do we achieve this?

input:

```
1|100437251|
2|51414204|
3|111651604|111651604
4|8321737|8321737
5|27263401|27263401
```

output:

```
1|100437251|100437251
2|51414204|51414204 
3|111651604|111651604
4|8321737|8321737
5|27263401|27263401
```

I have tried with `sed` command to replace `sed -i "s/ /$2/g" input > output`.

Comment: Note "`$3` is empty" does not mean "`$3` is space". The title and the body differ. Can there be a space character? or multiple? The field would be non-empty, yet blank; should it be replaced or not?

Comment: Where do the replacement values come rom?

Comment: if $3 empty means replace with $2 values.

Comment: Try this `sed "s/^\(.*\)|\(.*\)|\s*$/\1|\2|\2/" input > output`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk -F'|' -v OFS='|' '{if($3=="")$3=$2}1'
```

A simple `sed`, if the second column is always a number:

```
sed -E "s/([0-9]*)\|$/\1|\1/"
```

Answer (score 2):

#### With [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
sed -E 's/^([^|]*\|)([^|]*)\|$/\1\2|\2/' infile
```

this part `([^|]*\|)` capture the first column plus a delimiter too (`\1` is the back-reference).
this part `([^|]*)` capture the second column (`\2` is the back-reference).
this part `\|$` capture last delimiter that is end the line not anything else after (mean third column is empty).

this part `\1\2|\2` return the first and second columns back using back-references addresses and then a delimiter and duplicate the second column again.

---

if third column was not empty but also it may containing whitespace characters such as Tabs/Spaces (`[[:space:]]`), use this instead.

```
sed -E 's/^([^|]*\|)([^|]*)\|[[:space:]]*$/\1\2|\2/' infile
```

#### With [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="|" } $3 ~/^[[:space:]]*$/ { $3=$2 }1' infile
```

FS is the **F**ield **S**eparator, and OFS is the **O**utput **F**ield **S**eparator; then we checks if third column is empty/Tabs/Spaces, then update its content same as second column. then print `1`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`, and replacing the 3rd field with the 2nd unless the 3rd field contains non-blank characters:

```
$ awk -F '|' 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } $3 !~ /[^[:blank:]]/ { $3 = $2 }; 1' file
1|100437251|100437251
2|51414204|51414204
3|111651604|111651604
4|8321737|8321737
5|27263401|27263401
```

Using `sed` to insert the 2nd field's number if the 3rd field is empty or only contains blanks:

```
$ sed 's/\([[:digit:]]\{1,\}\)|[[:blank:]]*$/\1|\1/' file
1|100437251|100437251
2|51414204|51414204
3|111651604|111651604
4|8321737|8321737
5|27263401|27263401
```

---

Noticing that the 3rd field seems to *always* be the same as the 2nd field, we can also choose to ignore testing the 3rd field for anything and just force it to the 2rd field's value.

First, with `awk`:

```
$ awk -F '|' 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } { $3 = $2 }; 1' file
1|100437251|100437251
2|51414204|51414204
3|111651604|111651604
4|8321737|8321737
5|27263401|27263401
```

or even

```
$ awk -F '|' 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } { print NR, $2, $2 }' file
1|100437251|100437251
2|51414204|51414204
3|111651604|111651604
4|8321737|8321737
5|27263401|27263401
```

which also recreates the 1st column.

Then with `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/|[^|]*$//; s/[[:digit:]]\{1,\}$/&|&/' file
1|100437251|100437251
2|51414204|51414204
3|111651604|111651604
4|8321737|8321737
5|27263401|27263401
```

This `sed` command first deletes the last field, then recreates it from the field previous to the deleted field.

Or, something like

```
$ cut -d '|' -f 2 file | sed '=; s/.*/&|&/' | sed 'N; y/\n/|/'
1|100437251|100437251
2|51414204|51414204
3|111651604|111651604
4|8321737|8321737
5|27263401|27263401
```

which extracts the second field of the data with `cut`, then uses `=` in `sed` to enumerate the lines and create the duplication of the fields, and then finally attaches the line numbers to the data with the correct delimiter.

You could also do this with a combination of `cut` and `paste` in a shell like `bash` (with process substitutions):

```
$ paste -d '|' <( cut -d '|' -f 1,2 file ) <( cut -d '|' -f 2 file )
1|100437251|100437251
2|51414204|51414204
3|111651604|111651604
4|8321737|8321737
5|27263401|27263401
```

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`, to see if `$3` is empty (or not):

```
awk -F'|' -v OFS='|' '$3 == "" {$3=$2} 1' file
1|100437251|100437251
2|51414204|51414204
3|111651604|111651604
4|8321737|8321737
5|27263401|27263401
```

- or

```
awk -F'|' -v OFS='|' 'length($3) == 0 {$3=$2} 1' file
```